# Form setter option Symfony 3

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3 to build a website. I have an Entity (`Users`) that is in `OneToOne` relation with itself in order to make couples. (I didn't have others idea on how to do it easily)

The end goal is to create a form to reference the `id` of the other `Users` in the `couple`. So I created an `IntegerType` field and assign it the `id` but I can't set it (because there are no `setId(...)`). So I would know if there is a `setter` option (can't find in Doc/Tests), and if there isn't how could I achieve this ?

The steps to register a new couple would have been:

1. Send new id (of the other `Users`) [FORM]
2. Fetch the other `Users` (`$userCouple = ...findOne...`) [BDD]
3. If he have `$couple == null` then `$userCouple->setCouple($this)` and `$this->setCouple($userCouple)`

So my `Users` entity looks like:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;

/**
 * Users
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\UserBundle\Repository\UsersRepository")
 */
class Users extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Users")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $couple;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set couple.
     *
     * @param \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Users|null $couple
     *
     * @return Users
     */
    public function setCouple(\Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Users $couple = null)
    {
        $this->couple = $couple;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get couple.
     *
     * @return \Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Users|null
     */
    public function getCouple()
    {
        return $this->couple;
    }

}
```

And my form looks like :

```
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;

class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('couple', IntegerType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Couple ID',
            'property_path' => 'couple.id',
            'attr' => array('min' => 0),
        ));
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'acme_user_profile';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should solve this using a one-to-one self-referencing relation (see more [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-self-referencing)). Basically your `couple` would be replaced by `partner` which suites best the case:

```
...
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @JoinColumn(name="partner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $partner;
...
```

Then in the form you could use the `EntityType` (not sure why you wanted to use `IntegerType` in the first place) and do something like this:

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    // query choices from this entity
    'class' => 'UserBundle:User',

    // use the User.username property as the visible option string
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

Of course you can exclude the user you're editing the profile from the list of users you show as possible partners using `query_builder` option (passing a custom query) or `choices` to pass the collection of User entities you want to use (getting them first and filter out current user).

Comment: I had this solution, but thinking on how many users there will be (assuming 1000+) this is not suitable because the list will be too long...

Comment: On the frontend you can easily include tools like `select2` or similar in order to have autocomplete or search enabled widget input.

Comment: I can see your point. But the idea of `partner` is that both are `partners` and there I can say "I'm partner with you" but the other one won't be with me, plus I can't unlink from my partner.